# Check if complex values of dict matches certain criteria

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python dictionary with values being list of list:

```
dictionary={'sca4': [['BM1', 17], ['BM2', 33]], 'sca6': [['GM2', 46], ['GM2', 67], ['BM2', 17]]}
```

Please note that a number can be repeated in different keys, that is 17 in this case.

I have a text file with the following format:

```
sca4 15 25
sca4 20 32
sca6 45 62
```

I parsed the text file as follows:

```
for line in textfile.split("\n"):
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        col1, col2, col3 = line.strip().split(" ")
```

I want to see if each of the second elements of each list in the dictionary (that is 17, 33, 46, 67) falls within the range of the interval of col2 and col3 of the text file with the following code:

```
for value_list in dictionary.get(col1, []):
    if int(col2) <= value_list[1] <= int(col3):
      print "withinrange"
    else:
      print "outsiderange"
```

To have the output:

```
wihtinrange
outsiderange
withinrange
outsiderange
```

I don't get any error neither any output. It would be great if one could comment on my code and how I could debug it.

Comment: Can you publish the entire code?

Comment: if you're not getting any output it probably means that `dict.get(col1, [])` is not finding `col1` and returning `[]` instead so it never enters the loop. Also, `dict` is a reserved word in python, you should use a different name.

Comment: I tried to simplify my input files and the code for the question, I am afraid it gets too messy if I publish the entire code but I try to see how to make it simple to publish it.

Comment: Why there are two different limits for `sca4` but only one of `sca6`? What is a pattern here?

Comment: That's the coordinates of genes in my original file so there is repetition, that is one gene lies on sca4 in positions between 15 and 25 and the other on sca4 too but between 20 and 32 while for example, there is only one gene on sca6. There is no pattern in the original file, it is random how they are distributed.

Comment: So why exactly first two are `correct wrong` and not `wrong wrong`? When and why I'm changing those limits?

Comment: I actually ran your code and the output is `correct
wrong
wrong
wrong
correct
wrong` Does that makes sense to you ?

Comment: You could add an `else:` after the `for` which would execute if there was nothing to enumerate. Print the conditions to see what is different than expectations.

Comment: @anmol_uppal Exactly, that's the problem, there is something wrong with the for loop I think. The values are 17, 33, 46, 67 so 17 is between 15 and 25 so I want to print withinrange, 33 is outside so that is outsiderange and so on. I have four values so I must have four lines of output not more.

Comment: Wait a sec, your original question says you see no output. Do you see no output, or do you see 6 lines of output?

Comment: `17` is outside of `(20 32)` which is perfectly valid limit defined in your file... Why first limit matters and second does not?

Comment: after `print "withinrange"` add `continue` if it is not necessary to keep looking

Comment: Did you check if you parse the file and set col1, col2, col3 variables correctly? Maybe print those first and check. Because, your code should work. It works for me and @anmol_uppal  said it works for them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have added another answer with the extra requirements as specified in the comments of the previous posted answer:

```
def printList(l, dict1):
    for l1 in l:
        if dict1.has_key(l1):
            print "withinrange"
        else:
            print "outsiderange"

file = open("test1.txt")
textfile = file.readlines()
dict={'sca4': [['BM1', 17], ['BM2', 33]], 'sca6': [['GM2', 46], ['GM2', 67], ['BM',17]]}
dict1 = {}
l =[]
key = ''
for line in textfile:
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    col1, col2, col3 = line.strip().split(" ")
    if not (key == col1):
        printList(l, dict1)
        l =[]
        key = col1
        dict1 = {}
    for value_list in dict.get(col1, []):
        #print value_list[1]
        if not (value_list[1] in l):
            l.append(value_list[1])
        if ((int(col2) <= value_list[1]) and (value_list[1] <= int(col3))):
            dict1[value_list[1]] = 'correct'
printList(l, dict1)
```

Comment: I removed the "code snippet" markup from your answer. Code snippets are only for javascript, which this is not.

Comment: @shruti1810 Sorry for the delay, I was trying the code with my original data, it worked nicely, thanks again.

Comment: @DanGetz I added the extra information in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
file = open("test1.txt")
textfile = file.readlines()
dict={'sca4': [['BM1', 17], ['BM2', 33]], 'sca6': [['GM2', 46], ['GM2', 67]]}
dict1 = {}
l =[]
for line in textfile:
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    col1, col2, col3 = line.strip().split(" ")
    for value_list in dict.get(col1, []):
        #print value_list[1]
        if not (value_list[1] in l):
            l.append(value_list[1])
        if ((int(col2) <= value_list[1]) and (value_list[1] <= int(col3))):
            dict1[value_list[1]] = 'correct'
for l1 in l:
    if dict1.has_key(l1):
        print "withinrange"
    else:
        print "outsiderange"
```

Comment: Here test1.txt is the name of the file used.

Comment: You nailed it finally, congrats.

Comment: @shruti1810 This works so nicely for the test file. I need to go through it now and understand my mistakes and your corrections and test it for the actual file, will be back with the result.

Comment: @shruti1810 Oh, there is a problem with the actual data. In the actual data, I could have this case: `dict={'sca4': [['BM1', 17], ['BM2', 33]], 'sca6': [['GM2', 46], ['GM2', 67], ['BM', 17]]}` that is the repetition of a number but within another key, in this case, the code will ignore the number 17 in the 'sca6' which leads to wrong results in my problem. Although, that's my fault, I should have said this in the original question.

Comment: That will require that you start with empty list for each of the dictionary keys.

Comment: @user1945881 You will have to move the last for loop inside the first for loop. Are you not getting the desired output?

Comment: @user1945881 Not able to get the code, as it got printed in a single line.

Comment: @shruti1810 Oh, sorry, that was a mistake, I deleted my comment. I am now trying to see if I can get it right. When there is a simple dictionary, I can do it correctly but in this case that it has to match it with the column one of another file, I get it all wrong. But let me see what I can do, sorry again.

Comment: @shruti1810 What I have problem is updating the list everytime for each key. I inserted `l=[]` after `for value_list in dict.get(col1, []):` but this outputs each value in a single list if they pass the condition. I need to make the program in such a way that it creates a new list for each key. In a simple dictionary, I can loop through keys but here it is checking the condition from column1 of another file and then there are repetitions, that is two times we have one key. I am confused about that and could not make it work.

Comment: @user1945881 Can sca4 again appear after sca6 in file?

Comment: @shruti1810 no, because the file is sorted for all different 'sca's.

Comment: @user1945881 I have got the code, How shallI post it? Want me to add it as another answer?

Comment: @shruti1810 That's wonderful, thank you so much. Sure, you could add it as another answer, I will edit the original question so it matches it.

Comment: @user1945881 You need not edit the question, as people can go through these logs.

Comment: @shruti1810 actually, anything that's part of the question **should** be edited into the question. The entire question and answer should be able to be seen in the question and answer posts. Comments are supposed to be disposable. Notice that in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask they suggest editing missing information into the question, not just providing it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

actually your program goes like this through the data:

```
'sca4':
[['BM1', 17],  in interval(15, 25) -> "correct"
 ['BM2', 33]], in interval(15, 25) -> "wrong"
'sca4':
[['BM1', 17],  in interval(20, 32)  -> "wrong"
 ['BM2', 33]], in interval(20, 32) -> "wrong"

'sca6': 
[['GM2', 46], in interval(45, 62) -> "correct"
 ['GM2', 67]] in interval(45, 62) -> "wrong"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really helpful, it helped me to understand my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Another coding style:

```
import sys

dictionary = {'sca4': [['BM1', 17], ['BM2', 33]], 'sca6': [['GM2', 46], ['GM2', 67]]}

sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\AmmourKx\\Documents\\Python\\StackOverFlow')

text = open(sys.path[-1] + '\\2.txt')

for line in text:
    print line
    l = line.strip().split(' ')
    print l
    for i in range(len(dictionary.values())):
        if dictionary.get(l[0])[i][1] >= int(l[1]) and dictionary.get(l[0])[i][1] <= int(l[2]):
            print 'Within Range'
        else:
            print 'Outside Range'

text.close()
```